# NFA or e-NFA for the condition , n % 5 = 0 where n is the number of 1s

Tags: automata, finite-automata, automata-theory

How to create an NFA or eNFA that satisfies the condition

**n mod 5 = 0 where n is the number of 1s**

I made two NFAs and I am not sure if they are correct. I am confused if how many states should be there and what should be the final state. Am I allowed to loop back to q0 or should I just add another state?

[n mod 5 = 0 NFAs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Mo4z.png)

Answer (score 0):

From the given two images second diagram is the correct one.

Reason:

- first diagram is not satisfy the condition 0 mod 5 = 0
- second diagram satisfy all condition for n mod 5 = 0